# Puppeteer unable to use get property

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Cannot read property 'getProperty' of undefined is the error that I get.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scrapeUdemy(url) {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, slowmo: 250});
        const page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.goto(url)

        const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="udemy"]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/a/div[1]/div[1]');
        const txt = await el.getProperty('textContent');
        const rawTxt = await src.jsonValue();

        console.log({srcTxt});

        browser.close();
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
}

scrapeUdemy('https://www.udemy.com/user/eren-cem-salta/')
```

I tried using other versions but does not work. It is not working with the catch block too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element that you want to get is loaded with AJAX *after* the page started and you have to wait until it appears in the DOM:

```
await page.waitForSelector('[data-purpose="course-card-container"] div.udlite-heading-sm');
```

And why not use the same selector to get all of the cards:

```
const titles = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(
    '[data-purpose="course-card-container"] div.udlite-heading-sm'
  );
  return [...nodes].map((node) => node.textContent);
})
```

Comment: You should find the corresponding selector for images (usinf DevTools) and do the same :)